# Checking the multiplicative system definition for a class of maps in a triangulated category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I am reading these notes Derived categories, resolutions, and Brown representability
Henning Krause (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511047.pdf) about derived and triangulated categories

I am having trouble understanding the proof of condition MS3 in this lemma of section 3:

[image]
[image]

**1-How does one show that $\alpha -\beta$ factors through $\phi$?**

**2Why does $\tau$ belong to $S$ and $\tau\circ \alpha=\tau\circ\beta $**

Condition MS3:
[image]

In section 2.5 i ìt is stated what $\Sigma$ is
[image]

So I guess $\Sigma^n$ means a composition of n times $\Sigma$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, dont have time currently to tikz/tex the diagrams rigorously, hope that is ok.

regarding 1), consider the triangle
$$0\to Y \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} Y \to \Sigma 0$$ then you can map into that using $0$ and $\alpha-\beta$ such that the left square commutes and then you can fill that in to get factoring over $\psi$.

regarding 2) We know that $X''$ is the cone of $\sigma\in S$ so $0=H(\Sigma^n X'')$ (this is since$H(\Sigma^n\sigma)$ is an iso an iso for all $n$ and so, since $H$ is cohomological the third step in the long exact sequence, has to be zero).

This argument works the other way as well. In particular as $X''$ is the cocone of $\tau$ and has vanishing $H\left(\Sigma^n\right)$ we can conclude that $H(\Sigma^n \tau)$ is an isomorphism for all n and so $\tau\in S$. Furthermore, as we have a triangle $$X \xrightarrow{\alpha-\beta}Y\xrightarrow{\tau}X'' \to \Sigma X$$ we get $$0=(\alpha-\beta)\circ \tau=\alpha \circ \tau -\beta \circ\tau $$ and so $$\alpha \circ \tau=\beta \circ \tau.$$